# bootstrap - add label to span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following markup

```
<form role="form">                      
   <div class="input-group">
    <label for="accountSpan">Account name</label>
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="accountSpan">something</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="account name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="accountInput" >
                    </div>                                              
                    <div class="form-group">                             
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>                         
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />                       
                    </div>
    </form>
```

which results in

[image]

How can I have it aligned like the password?

Comment: use class `.form-control` on it

Comment: @GauravAggarwal thanks for your input, but I have no idea where to add that to, css is reall not my thing :(

Comment: to the element which you want to look like password

Comment: @GauravAggarwal fixed already, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19193/)**

If you use `form-group` along with `input-group` like you did for password, you can get your expected output.

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="accountSpan">Account name</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="accountSpan">something</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="account name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="accountInput">

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

<form role="form"> 
<div class="input-group"> 
  <label for="accountSpan">Account name</label> 
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="accountSpan">something</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="account name" 
  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="accountInput" > 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label> 
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your answer [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhq2mesx/):

```
<form role="form">      
       <div class="form-group">   
            <label for="accountSpan">Account name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="accountSpan">something</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="account name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="accountInput" >
                </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">                             
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>                         
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" />                       
        </div>
    </form>
```